# How to return array of foreign rows in SQLITE?

Tags: sql, arrays, sqlite, select

first off, my SQL skills are marginal at best. I'm working with an SQLite database, and I'd like to avoid cluttering my application code with too many filtering functions. What I'm looking for is an SQL statement that integrates multiple rows of another table into an array. I've searched for quite a while now, but I'm not even sure what the right keywords are.

Anyway, these are my tables...

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (identifier PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE table_b (identifier PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT UNIQUE, fk_a INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(fk_a) REFERENCES table_a(identifier);
```

table_a:

```
1 | ABC
2 | DEF
3 | GHI
```

table_b:

```
1 | abc | 1
2 | def | 1
3 | ghi | 2
```

...and now I'm looking for a statement which returns a row in table_a with all corresponding rows from table_b within an array:

```
1 | ABC | [1 | abc | 1, 2 | def | 1]
```

Is this possible at all? If it is... what's the most concise way to write this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want `group_concat()`:

```
select a.identifier, a.name,
  '[' || group_concat(b.identifier ||  ' | ' ||  b.name ||  ' | ' || b.fk_a) || ']' col
from table_a a left join table_b b
on b.fk_a = a.identifier
group by a.identifier, a.name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVgY1khqo7M6qt1oiwhnuK/1).
Results:

```
| identifier | name | col                       |
| ---------- | ---- | ------------------------- |
| 1          | ABC  | [1 | abc | 1,2 | def | 1] |
| 2          | DEF  | [3 | ghi | 2]             |
| 3          | GHI  |                           |
```

or if you prefer with `json_group_array()`:

```
select a.identifier, a.name,
  json_group_array(b.identifier ||  ' | ' ||  b.name ||  ' | ' || b.fk_a) col
from table_a a left join table_b b
on b.fk_a = a.identifier
group by a.identifier, a.name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVgY1khqo7M6qt1oiwhnuK/2).
Results:

```
| identifier | name | col                           |
| ---------- | ---- | ----------------------------- |
| 1          | ABC  | ["1 | abc | 1","2 | def | 1"] |
| 2          | DEF  | ["3 | ghi | 2"]               |
| 3          | GHI  | [null]                        |
```

You may use:

```
replace(json_group_array(b.identifier ||  ' | ' ||  b.name ||  ' | ' || b.fk_a), '"', '')
```

if you don't want the double quotes.

Comment: Man, thanks a lot! By using 'json_group_object' it gets even better. Just have to figure out how to enable the json_* functions, but that won't be a problem I guess-- it's working perfectly in the fiddle. Thank you!!